# Rspec does not memoize indirect changes made to factorygirl object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a factory girl factory that looks something like:

```
FactoryDefine do
  factory :capture do
    attribute1 nil
    factory :capture_with_images do
      after(:create) do
        FactoryGirl.create(:image, capture: image)
      end
    end
 end
```

When the image object gets created, it updates attribute1 in its parent via a callback. This works fine.

My rspec looks something like this

```
describe Capture do
  shared_examples "with images" do
    it "has attribute assigned" do
      expect(subject.attribute1).to be_present
    end
  end
  describe do
    subject { FactoryGirl.create(:capture_with_images) }
    include_examples "with images"
  end
end
```

The problem? At `expect(subject.attribute1).to be_present` the subject has attribute1 set to nil. Using the debugger, I can see that the Capture stored in the test database has attribute1 set, but not the subject, therefore I know the callback in my Image are working and propagating the attribute to the parent.

It seems that rspec memoizes the object attributes before after(:create) is callback, and is unable to update. Is this a bug or am I using it in an unexpected way (or just doing it wrong)?

Thanks for listening

Comment: `expect` wants a block. Try `expect { subject.attribute1 }`

Comment: I should mention I'm using the latest version of rspec (2.12). In the latest versions expect can take an argument (and will be the new standard, replacing should)

Comment: Hmm. Your factory has `attribute1 nil`. That would make `be_present` return false, no?

Comment: "When the image object gets created, it updates attribute1 in its parent via a callback". Sorry if this is unclear. The image is a child of the capture. The image gets created after the capture, but when the image is created, it updates attribute1 of the capture. So initially, yes the attribute1 is nil, but after the child is created it is not nil.

Comment: Well I'm all out of guesses. I'd encourage you to post more code so other folks can have something more go to on.